# SQL-syntax error

Tags: sql

What is wrong with this SQL-syntax?

```
INSERT INTO chatt (user, msg, ip) VALUES('testUser', 'testMsg', '81.235.154.103')
```

The server is running some IIS with an unknown SQL version, but the files has to be in access 2000-format. The fields i've got are id, user, msg, ip, datum. 1st one is a counter, last one is a date/time and the rest are text fields. How do i insert into those three fields?

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the actual error message we can't really tell, but two obvious things jump out:

- `user` is a reserved word; enclose it in square braces: `[user]`
- Your `datum` field may be `not null`, which means you need to provide a value for it in your statement.

Answer (score 4):

`user` may be a reserved word.  Try putting it in brackets `[user]`